# PHP foreach loop in HTML table 2 per row

Tags: php, loops

I have the following PHP loop

```
foreach ($users as $key => $name){
    echo $name;
}
```

It displays quite a few names. I want to display it inside a table column td but after every 2 i want to start a new row. So the table I want to look like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="center">$name</td>
<td width="50%" align="center">$name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="center">$name</td>
<td width="50%" align="center">$name</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Therefore creating a new table row after every 2 in the loop.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<table><tr>';
$i=0;
foreach ($users as $key => $name){
    if($i%2==0 && $i!=0)
    {
     echo '</tr><tr><td width="50%" align="center">'.$name.'</td>';
    }
   else
    echo '<td width="50%" align="center">'.$name.'</td>';
  $i++;
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

> Try this

Comment: i tried it but seems like you are missing the closing tag for tr. I put one in right at the end before the closing tag of the table and i also put one in just before the tr tag in the if condition

Comment: @Ahmed table will be take automatically closing tag

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <?php $i = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach($users as $key => $name) ?>
        <?php if($i > 2) { $i = 0; } ?>
        <?php if($i == 2 || $key == 0) { ?>
            <tr>
        <?php } ?>
            <td width="50%" align="center">$name</td>
            <td width="50%" align="center">$name</td>
        <?php if($i == 2 || $key == 0) { ?>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$count = count($users);
$c = 0;
foreach ($users as $key => $name){ ?>

    <?php if ($c%2 === 0) {?>
        <table width="100%" border="0">
    <?php } ?>

        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="center">$name</td>
            <td width="50%" align="center">$name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="center">$name</td>
            <td width="50%" align="center">$name</td>
        </tr>

    <?php if ($c%2 === 1 || $count == ($c+1)) {?>
        </table>
    <?php } ?>

<?php $c++; } ?>
```